# UI button does not respond after exporting an entire game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a project that unifies few small unity games to one game, every game works perfectly on its own. After importing one of the games the UI buttons in this game stopped responding.

I've compared every element in the scene to its working counter part, there is NO difference. 
I've tried to add a `Debug.Log("msg")` inside the method to see if there is a response from the code and there is none.
I've created a new button that calls to the same script that manages the scenes - not working.

Then I've created another script that had only:

```
public void LoadScene(string sceneName)
{
    Debug.Log("here");
    if(sceneName == null)
    {
        sceneName = defualtSceneName;
    }
    SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
}
```

and attached it to an empty game object and I've made the button call for this method, again nothing.
Lastly I've added:

```
private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Debug.Log("here12");
        LoadScene(defualtSceneName);
    }
}
```

This loads the the scene but it disables other options in the scene.
BTW I'm working with unity V 2019.2.0f

Comment: Are you sure there's an `EventSystem` in the Scene?

Comment: yep it's there...

Comment: Check the heirarchy to see if you have a panel over the top of the buttons blocking them (Lower down in the order)

Comment: I don't have anything it the new project that is not in the old one, nor in a different place

Comment: If the game still runs, but UI elements aren't responding, it might be a good idea to examine the `EventSystem`'s output.  Have a look at the preview box on the inspector window of the `EventSystem` while running your game.  You should see various outputs about the mouse state (like what UI element your mouse is over).  Make sure that all the values there line up, and it properly detects the UI elements that you hover over.

Comment: Did you check the `GraphicsRaycaster` of the `Canvas`? Or do you by any chance remove the events by code?

Comment: Thanks, @DouglasDwyer your debug method helped me to understand what was it, eventually it was the main canvas - it was defined in an unidentified layer, thus I couldn't hover over anything in it.